# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' for WSGI and Apache

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi, wsgi

When trying to configure a production setup for WSGI and a Django app, I have run into an issue. Namely, I get the following error in the Apache 2 error log:

```
[Sun Jan 12 22:27:11.572677 2020] [core:notice] [pid 26686:tid 140092282805184] AH00051: child pid 27359 exit signal Aborted (6), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

I am closely following the configurations of another, working app when it comes to `wsgi.py` and the `mod_wsgi`. The one major difference is that this is a new EC2 (Ubuntu 18) instance, on which I had to rebuild Python 3.7 from scratch. To build the Python, I (mostly) followed [THESE STEPS](https://thecustomizewindows.com/2017/10/install-miniconda-ubuntucentos/), substituting 3.5 for 3.7

After that, I installed Miniconda and created a new virtual environment in it using Python 3.7.

I have checked permissions on the directories which contain the source code and the virtual environments. Both of those have `www-data` as the group.

What else can I check to fix this? If there is any code or configs that will be useful to see, please let me know.

Comment: _After that, I installed Miniconda and created a new virtual environment in it using Python 3.7._ Is that the environment you're using when you get this error?

Comment: Correct. I can launch the development server successfully using that environment, but when used via Apache and WSGI it doesn’t seem to work.

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @SMoenig I did. However, I do not recall what the issue was. It is possible that the discussion here (towards the bottom) may be of use to you, but I am unsure.

https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/338

Comment: P.S. You may want to ask GrahamDumpleton from that thread. He is a VERY knowledgeable guy.